# WCF Service not available from public IP

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I've a WCF Windows Service self-hosted over https with Transport in https://myserver.mydomain.com .

When I try to open https://myserver.mydomain.com in any browser localy (means from wcf server for instance), i get a http 502 error. Same issue if i use its public IP.   It works if i use its internal IP but i need to manualy accept ssl certificate because of wrong server name.
Please not that https://myserver.mydomain.com is accessible from internet, so outside my prod environnement!

Could you help me to identify where I should focus my effort to solve it?

Is it due to binding configuration? X509 certificate? App.config? Elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my issue was due to a NAT rule which had a strange behavior. This rule forwarded all packets from an internal IP to server internal IP. We added a new rule to go through Firewall and all is working fine now!

So, only one recommandation if someone else have this issue: be careful with your Firewall configuration (Sophos in my case)...